# SelectRaw() not working in Laravel 5.5 Eloquent if it is included inside a with() function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm pretty much new to Laravel but the Eloquent is pretty much the same with Yii's ActiveRecord and I am very familiar with it.

I was trying to fetch rows from table and I already defined the relationships and it worked well. It returns all the values, except when a selectRaw function is used.

```
return $this->select('id', 'name', 'longitude', 'latitude')->with([
        'dailyWaterLevel' => function($dailyWaterLevel) {
            $dailyWaterLevel->select('id', 'dams_id', 'excel_identifier', 'rwl', 'rc', 'sl', 'nhwl', 'lwl')
                ->whereRaw('MONTH(str_to_date(excel_identifier, "%m")) = ?', [date('m')])
                ->whereRaw('id in (select max(id) from dams_details where dams_id = dams_id and MONTH(str_to_date(excel_identifier, "%m")) = ? group by excel_identifier, dams_id)', [date('m')])
                ->orderBy('excel_identifier', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }, 'lowestWaterLevel' => function($lowestWaterLevel) {
            $lowestWaterLevel->select('id', 'dams_id', 'excel_identifier', 'rwl')
                ->orderBy('rwl', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('excel_identifier', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }, 'highestWaterLevel' => function($highestWaterLevel) {
            $highestWaterLevel->select('id', 'dams_id', 'excel_identifier', 'rwl')
                ->orderBy('rwl', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('excel_identifier', 'desc')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }, 'averageMonthlyWaterLevel' => function($averageMonthlyWaterLevel) {
            $averageMonthlyWaterLevel->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(excel_identifier, "%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%Y") as month_year, format(avg(rwl), 2) as average_rwl')
                ->whereRaw('YEAR(str_to_date(excel_identifier, "%m-%d-%Y")) = ?', [date('Y')])
                ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(excel_identifier, "%m-%d-%Y"), "%m-%Y")'))
                ->orderBy('excel_identifier', 'desc');
        }])->get()->toArray();
```

As you can see I have raw SQL functions on some relationships and they work. Except for the "averageMonthlyWaterLevel" relationship.

I tried it outside a relationship clause and it works. But whenever I put it inside a relationship clause it doesn't work. I also tried DB::raw inside the select query and it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay now I just forgot to add the primary keys on the select query!